# SQL query not returning all data - only half of it

Tags: sql, report, birt

I have a SQL query that's only pulling data from 2012 - 2014. However, I know there's more data since we're in 2018 but it's not pulling. I need to get it to where it pulls the all dates. Here's my code.

```
select 
    PA.STUD_ID AS STUDENT_ID,
    LS.SEQ_NUM AS SEQ_NUM,
    LS.LOGIN_ID AS LOGIN_ID,
    LS.LOGIN_TYPE AS LOGIN_TYPE,
    LS.SESSION_ID AS SESSION_ID,
    LS.LOGIN_TIME AS LOGIN_TIME,
    LS.LOGOUT_TIME AS LOGOUT_TIME,
    LS.LST_UPD_USR AS LAST_USER_UPDATED,
    LS.LST_UPD_TSTMP AS LAST_TIME_STAMP,
    LA.ATTEMPT_SUCCESSFUL AS SUCCESSFUL_ATTEMPT
FROM
    PA_STUDENT PA,
    PA_STUD_LOGIN_ATTEMPT LA,
    PA_LOGIN_SESSION_INFO LS
WHERE 
    PA.STUD_ID = LA.STUD_ID
    AND LA.SEQ_NUM = LS.SEQ_NUM
    /** AND LOGIN_TIME >= [AuditDateRangeFrom] 
    AND NOT LOGIN_TIME > [AuditDateRangeTo] */
    /** AND [security:PA_STUDENT PA] 
    */
```

Comment: Most likely you need to be using `outer joins` instead.  Does the data only exist in 1 of the tables?  In general I'd recommend not using commas in your `from` clause, but rather explicit `joins` instead.

Comment: You'll need to post sample data so we can reproduce your issue. Logically there doesn't look to be a problem with your query (Syntactically though, you should explicitly write joins rather than using that old syntax).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your tables are named "PA", "LS", & "LA" based on your syntax for the fields you are attempting to return. If this is the case your FROM section should be something like:

```
FROM PA OUTER JOIN LA ON PA.STUD_ID = LA.STUD_ID OUTER JOIN LS ON LA.SEQ_NUM = LS.SEQ_NUM
```

It appears you are attempting to use the WHERE clause to tell the tables how to join, but that should be in the FROM clause.

Basically, your syntax in the FROM clause doesn't make sense unless your tables actually are named "PA_STUDENT PA" , but if that is the case your SELECT portion doesn't make sense.